# Convert Informix file into pdf

Tags: pdf, informix

Is it possible to convert file into PDF directly from Informix?
Is there a command for it? If its not possible, then what should I do?
For example: I want to convert file sm2026.4gl into PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly, it looks like you're trying to get a PDF version of a 4GL program, which doesn't make any sense. There are any number of [free websites](https://duckduckgo.com/convert%20text%20to%20PDF?ia=web) that can do this for you.

If, however, you're asking how to get a 4GL report to generate a PDF, that's a considerably more interesting problem. Informix-4GL will not write a PDF file natively. If I remember correctly, 4Js Genero will, and Querix Lycia might.

However, on Linux, there is a PDF printer driver (cups-pdf) that will output the report to a PDF file.

Implementation of this is left as an exercise to the reader. :-)

Comment: Sorry for the error in question. "how to get a 4GL report to generate a PDF". This what I'm looking for. Is there any way that I can make Informix-4GL to save report as PDF?

Comment: Can you tell me what distribution and version of Linux or Unix you're on?

Comment: I'm running Informix4gl on Windows 7 using TinyTerm Terminal Emulator.

Comment: OK, you definitely aren't running Informix-4GL on Windows 7! :-)

TinyTerm must be connecting you to some kind of Linux or Unix box, In TinyTerm, what is the output from "uname -a"?

Comment: SunOS BGRP 5.10 Generic_138888-03 sun4v sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200

Comment: If you install the ghostscript_filters (and dependencies) from https://www.opencsw.org/packages/ghostscript_filters/ then you should be able to the information at https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.26/Unix-lpr.htm to configure Ghostscript as a "printer". In your 4GL program, you would then "START REPORT whatever TO PIPE 'lp -d my_pdf_printer'"

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options available to you.  What you choose will depend on how much time and money you are prepared to invest.  The more you are prepared to invest, the better reports you will get

1. Do a google search for scripts/executables that will take a text file and convert to PDF.  Examples include txt2pdf.  These work on any text files and so are independent of the 4gl.  You would amend your 4gl code to execute this via RUN immediately after your FINISH REPORT
2. Write 4gl libraries to create valid PDF output.  That involves you reading the PDF manuals to see the structure required in a PDF file.  The first line of the resulting file will begin "%PDF".  This is a lot of work, I did it 15-20 years ago, I wouldn't do it again unless you want the control and independence this gives you.
3. Using a product such as FourJs Genero that will allow you to use your existing 4gl code to create PDF reports directly.  At its simplest this involves adding a couple of lines prior to your START REPORT and leaving the REPORT statement intact.  The report will use a monospaced font and look like your existing report, only it is a PDF instead of a TXT file.

   ```
   IF fgl_report_loadCurrentSettings(NULL) THEN -- simple compatibility mode
       CALL fgl_report_selectDevice("PDF")      -- indicates PDF 
       ...  -- optional calls to indicate filename, paper, printer and other options if required
       LET grw = fgl_report_commitCurrentSettings()

       START REPORT report-name TO XML HANDLER grw
   ```

Using this option there are a few extra config options that are available such as adding watermarks/logos to every page that the free tools you find might not provide

4. The more feature rich option using FourJs Genero Report Writer involves stripping out any layout information from your 4gl code and designing the layout of the report in a WYSIWYG designer.  Your 4gl code that gathers the data from the database and the functions that formulate the output is untouched.  The REPORT statement no longer requires the layout information such as COLUMN 10, SKIP TO TOP OF PAGE, and that can be removed.  The WYSIWYG design of the report controls the layout including full range of properties such as font, font attributes, positioning, page breaks, page numbering, images.  So your 4gl code becomes

   ```
   -- Report
   -- No layout information in report, only need to gather and formulate data
   REPORT report-name ...
       BEFORE GROUP OF invoice
           PRINT invoice.*       
       ON EVERY ROW
           PRINT invoice_line.* 
       AFTER GROUP OF invoice
           LET invoice_total.net = GROUP SUM(...)
           PRINT invoice_total.* 
   END REPORT
   ...
   -- Produce report 
   IF fgl_report_loadCurrentSettings("reportdesign.4rp") THEN -- load the WYSIWYG design
       CALL fgl_report_selectDevice("PDF")      -- indicates PDF 
       ...  -- calls to indicate filename, paper, printer and other options if required
       LET grw = fgl_report_commitCurrentSettings()

       START REPORT report-name TO XML HANDLER grw
   ```

As shown there are a number of options available to you. As to what you should do, that depends on what your goal is, and how much time and money you are prepared to invest to achieve that goal.

Comment: I can't do number 1 since Infomix4gl report in not in text format.
I'll try using FourJs Genero. Can you explain more on number 2.

Comment: If it is not in text format, what format is it in?  Re #2 you need to find a document that details the PDF specification.  It will take you a long time.  When I did it 15-20 years ago I was fortunate in that I had already written some 4gl libraries to create Postscript and PCL documents and it was a simple case of extending these to PDF.  With #2 you are looking at weeks/months not hours/days.  Options #1, #3 will get you a solution measured in hours. #4 a little longer as you WYSIWYG design the report and  learn the nuances of the designer